# Ternary extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, extension-methods, razor

I created the following HtmlHelper extension method for my Asp.Net MVC Razor views because the ternary syntax sucks when you need to use it intermixed with markup.

Is there a better way to write this and are there any potential type safety issues with it?

```
public static string GetValueTernary(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object a, object b, object valueIfEqual, object valueIfNotEqual)
{
    return a.Equals(b) ? valueIfEqual.ToString() : valueIfNotEqual.ToString();
}
```

and its usage in a Razor view is like this:

```
<div class="@Html.GetValueTernary(Model.UserVoteTypeId, VoteType.UpVote, "us", "u")">...</div>
```

Comment: Main issue I can see is that all arguments will be evaluated no matter what. Also your code could be factorised out : `return (a.Equals(b) ? valueIfEqual : valueIfNotEqual).ToString()`

Comment: Can't you instead write `<div class="@(Model.UserVoteTypeId == VoteType.UpVote ? "us" : "u")">...</div>`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would change your method to use generics (so that the return value is meaningful) and not call `.ToString()` internally. This will enable you to use it in more scenarios.

```
public static T GetValueTernary<T>(this HtmlHelper html, object a, object b, T valueIfEqual, T valueIfNotEqual)
{
    return object.Equals(a, b) ? valueIfEqual : valueIfNotEqual;
}
```

Now you can use it like this as well and also it will enable you to use `HtmlString`-s as values.

```
<div class="@Html.GetValueTernary(Model.UserVoteTypeId, VoteType.UpVote, "us", "u").ToUpper()">...</div>
```

You could also benefit (depends on your actual usage) from not using `object` for the compared values - by using a generic the compiler will complain if the types of the two are not compatible (for example, you are comparing `string` to `int`):

```
public static TReturn GetValueTernary<TValue, TReturn>(this HtmlHelper html, TValue a, TValue b, TReturn valueIfEqual, TReturn valueIfNotEqual)
{
    return object.Equals(a, b) ? valueIfEqual : valueIfNotEqual;
}
```

Comment: p.s. `object.Equals` bit was borrowed from the answer by @svick

Answer (score 10):

Your code will throw an exception when `a` is `null`. A safe way to compare values is [the static version of `object.Equals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k):

```
object.Equals(a, b)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do this a little differently...

```
/// <summary>
/// Uses <see cref="EqualityComparer{TValue}"/> to determine if <paramref name="left"/> is
/// equal to <paramref name="right"/>. If it is, <paramref name="returnIfEqual"/> is returned,
/// otherwise, <paramref name="returnIfNotEqual" /> is returned.
/// </summary>
public static TResult IfEqualReturn<TValue, TResult>(this HtmlHelper html, TValue left, TValue right, TResult returnIfEqual, TResult returnIfNotEqual)
{
    return EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(left, right) ? returnIfEqual : returnIfNotEqual;
}
```

**Notes:**

- Use generics instead of `object` [to avoid boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).
- Use [`EqualityComparer<TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123.aspx) to check for equality. This class is very efficient, avoids boxing, and does a good job of handling the primitive types correctly, uses [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) if `TValue` implements it, and correctly evaluates reference equality versus value equality depending on `TValue`. It also will not throw an exception if `left` or `right` is null.
- When you create any function (but extensions methods in particular), choosing a descriptive but succinct name is *critical*. Ideally, the name should be enough information for another developer to know what the function does without looking at its code.

  - I chose `IfEqualReturn` because, to me, the most important thing to understand about the function is that it evaluates the equality of `left` and `right` to determine what to return-- remember, any boolean value can be used for a [ternary expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx), so `GetValueTernary` leaves out the critical detail that this function specifically evaluates equality.
  - Using [XML comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) is particularly important for extension methods. When you write your [`<summary>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d6dt3kf.aspx), imagine that another developer is reading your code, and explain what he would need to know to understand what the call will do. Keep it brief-- it should fit easily in a tooltip. If you feel like you need to explain more, add a [`<remarks>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zw4z1ys.aspx) element.

---

Here are some other suggestions.

The [.NET Framework interface `IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) allows you to create classes that evaluate equality of a given type `T`. The following function allows someone to pass in an instance, and falls back on `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` if one is not specified.

```
public static TResult IfEqualReturn<TValue, TResult>(this HtmlHelper html, TValue left, TValue right, TResult resultIfEqual, TResult resultIfNotEqual, IEqualityComparer<TValue> equalityComparer = null)
{
    if (equalityComparer == null) 
        equalityComparer = EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;

    return equalityComparer.Equals(left, right) ? resultIfEqual : resultIfNotEqual;
}
```

One place where this comes in handy is when comparing strings (see [StringComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Usage:

```
var r1 = Html.IfEqualReturn("str1", "str2", true, false, StringComparer.Invariant); // r1 = false
var r2 = Html.IfEqualReturn("str1", "str1", true, false, StringComparer.Invariant); // r2 = true
var r3 = Html.IfEqualReturn("str1", "STR1", true, false, StringComparer.Invariant); // r3 = false
var r4 = Html.IfEqualReturn("str1", "STR1", true, false, StringComparer.InvariantIgnoreCase); // r4 = true
```

... or you could create one that uses a lambda expression:

```
public static TResult IfTrueThen<TValue, TResult>(this HtmlHelper html, TValue left, TValue right, TResult returnIfTrue, TResult returnIfFalse, Func<TValue, TValue, bool> evaluateFunc)
{
    return evaluateFunc(left, right) ? returnIfTrue : returnIfFalse;
}

// Usage:
var r1 = Html.IfTrueThen(0, 1, true, false, (l, r) => l == r); // r1 = false
var r2 = Html.IfTrueThen("string", "STRING", true, false, (l, r) => String.Equals(l, r, StringComparison.InvariantIgnoreCase)); // r2 = true
```

Another way:

```
public static TResult IfTrueThen<TResult>(this HtmlHelper html, Func<HtmlHelper, bool> evaluateFunc, TResult resultIfTrue, TResult resultIfFalse)
{
    return evaluateFunc(html) ? resultIfTrue : resultIfFalse;
}

// Usage:
int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
var r1 = Html.IfTrueThen(h => v1 == v2, true, false); // r1 = true

v1 = 4;
var r2 = Html.IfTrueThen(h => v1 == v2, true, false); // r2 = false
var r3 = Html.IfTrueThen(h => (v1 - 4) == v2, true, false); // r3 = true
```

or...

```
<div class="@Html.IfTrueThen(h => Model.UserVoteTypeId == VoteType.UpVote, "us", "u")">...</div>
```